# What is the best way to structure my data model in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a route that sends to me many requests over time, that contain data to stored in a model.

So the first request does not contain all the needed data and I need to parse each request every time new information comes and store it.

Actually I have a separate js file which contains the "model" and methods

```
const request = require('request-promise');

function Conversation(param) {
console.log(param)
    this.endpoint  ;
    this.id = this.getConvId(param);
    this.createdOn = Date.now();
    this.to = this.getTo(param);
    this.from = this.getFrom(param);
    this.state = this.getState(param);
    this.importance = this.getImportance(param);
    this.threadId = this.getT;
    this.subject = this.getSubject(param);
    this.name=this.getName(param);


}

Conversation.prototype.sendIM =function sendIM(param) {
   // method to send message to a user
}

Conversation.prototype.getConvId = function getConvId(param) {
    return param.operationId
};
Conversation.prototype.getTo = function getTo(param) {
    return param.to
}
Conversation.prototype.getDirection = function getDirection(param) {
    return param.direction
}
Conversation.prototype.getState = function getState(param) {
    return param.state
}
Conversation.prototype.getOperationId = function getOperationId(param) {
    return param.sender[0].events[0]._embedded["service:messagingInvitation"].opertionId
}
Conversation.prototype.getImportance = function getSubject(param) {
    return param.importance;
}
Conversation.prototype.getSubject = function getSubject(param) {
    return param.sender[0].events[0]._embedded["service:messagingInvitation"].subject
}
Conversation.prototype.getFrom= function getFrom(param) {
    return param._embedded["localParticipant"].uri
}
Conversation.prototype.getName= function getName(param) {
    return param._embedded["acceptedByParticipant"].name
}

module.exports = Conversation;
```

In my main app file  I create a new conversation object:

```
var Conversation= require('./Conversation');


app.post('/callback', function (req, res) {
    if(req.body.sender.length==0) {
        res.status(200).send();
    }

    if(req.body.sender.length>0) {
        const conv = new Conversation(req.body.sender[0].events[0]._embedded['service:messagingInvitation']);
        res.status(200).send();
    }
 })
```

the method works well when I have to fill the model once, but when I update an item it becomes complicated.

So I would like to know what is the best way to structure my files so that I will be able to add new data to my model over time ?

Comment: None of those `getX` methods should be an instance method. Make it a plain function in the module, make it a static class method if necessary, or just inline it into the constructor (especially the simple cases that just access a property).

Comment: `const conv = new Conversation(req.body.…)` - and then you do what with `conv`? If you're not doing anything, why are you constructing it at all?

Comment: I will use `conv` to send back messages to user

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear from the code you posted.